# How to achieve inversion of control in a front controller pattern?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm stuck at making dependency injection between controllers-services, services-database, I feel like it's a mess.

All the requests are redirected to index.php from public_html, in there

In index.php from public_html, I'm creating an app object, serving it a router and set up some routes like:

```
$app = new Application(new Router());
$app->addRoute('/questions', (Object)[
   'controller' => 'QuestionsController',
   'action' => 'getAllQuestions'
]);
```

I'm matching the URI against regex routes and instantiating the controller somehow "dynamically" depending on the route inside Application.php which maps to a controller and an action:

```
 if(class_exists($this->controllerNamespace)){
  $this->router->setController(new $this->controllerNamespace);
  call_user_func_array([$this->router->getController(), $this->router->getAction()], [$this->router->getParams()]);
 }
```

Inside the controller, I would instantiate a Service object and call a method on the service to retrieve db results.

The service in turn needs a database object in order to interact with the database and my database class is something like a singleton I suppose:

```
static function getInstance():Database
{
    if (NULL == self::$database) {
        self::$database = new Database();
    }
    return self::$database;
}
```

so I wouldn't know what service the controller needs until I'm actually inside the controller and the database instantiated inside the service class just seems wrong, how can I improve the whole thing?

My preference is without other libs for a dependency injection controller or other stuff that makes it easy, I'm writing this as a learning exercise to understand it better.

```
app
 src
  Controllers
   Questions
   Answers
  Core
   Controller
   Database
   Router
   Service
   View
  Services
   Questions
   Answers
  Views
   index.php
  Application.php
  Config.php
 tests
 vendor
logs
public_html
 assets
 index.php
 .htaccess
```